# macOS make command work recursively

Tags: bash, macos, recursion

I have tried a lot of things regarding renaming of objects. I found out that the following command proved to be working rock solid and properly:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | tr ‘:’ '_'`"; done
```

Unfortunately this command is not working recursivley.

My "target" folder for this command is a share /Volumes/Share/Work\ Data/. Is there a "simple" way to make it recursively?

Dan

Comment: The "simple" way could be `shopt -s globstar; for f in **/*` - but unfortunately this needs bash 4.0 - and the default OSX bash is only 3.2.57.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` with bash substitution:

```
find . -name "*:*" -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" "${0//:/_}"' {} \;
```

The command above will do a "dry-run" of the move operation. When you are confident that the files are named as you want replace `echo` with `mv` to actually move/rename the files recursively.

Comment: the dry run looked very good - another question: can I time it to automatically start in t+5h when my backup is completed (will not be awake until then)

Comment: Yes, you could do something such as `find <the command above> | at noon`, or `find ... | at 1:00`, etc. another way is to create a `launchd` or `cron` job, although for a convenient way to execute a command at a certain time, `| at ...` usually works great.

Comment: @swift_dan - I prefer `| at` for one off jobs. If it is recurring, then use `cron`.

Comment: @jm666 that is true. But since this is one time I mean 08:00 pm + 5h = 01:00 am, so both are right

Comment: well @l'L'l, something went wrong: find . -name "*:*" -exec bash -c 'mv "${0//:/_}"' {} \; | at 02:00
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: @swift_dan - it looks like you missed the first parameter to `mv`. you are missing `"$0"`.

Comment: @alvits: you're right...and this one... find: ./path cleaned/Redesign_2015:16: No such file or directory...I did not know that my collegues also named folders "wrong"...

Comment: @swift_dan - The directory was renamed while find already has it in the list. You could add `-depth` so it will rename all the files before renaming the parent directories.

Comment: @swift_dan: You can also use `-type f` to only do files perhaps, and `-type d` for directories.

Comment: `sleep 18000; find ...` for a 5 hour delay

Comment: @MarkSetchell: That would probably work also, although the same could be done with `cmd | at now + 5 hours`, or `cmd | at now + 300 minutes`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *, which only lists files in the current directory, use `find .`, which recurses through directories. Example:

```
for f in `find .`; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | tr ‘:’ '_'`"; done
```

Comment: ... and will blow up in filenames containing spaces.

Comment: Why use `for` in conjunction with `find` when `find` alone can do the job safely?

Comment: you both are right, I used the below command in dry run and it worked very well. everything that should be found was found!